# Why are rebel groups always situated in the Rocky Mountains?

Tags: american-cinema

I've seen several such plots, now -- an authoritarian government now rules the United States, and a rebellion is brewing in the Rocky Mountains. An example would be "The Man in the High Castle".

It's not just restricted to movies, either -- even fictional novels for kids, such as "The Maze Runner" and Erin Bowman's "Taken" have this theme.

Is this because of the perception of the American West (minus coastal cities) as libertarian? That might've been the reason Galt's Gulch in Atlas Shrugged was in Colorado, but most fiction writers, be it Hollywood or novelists, could hardly be considered libertarians or even conservatives.

Comment: Generally speaking, mountainous terrain is difficult to navigate and sparsely populated.  Both good qualities for any group trying to evade an overwhelming enemy force, such as a totalitarian regime in control of the country.

Comment: You might be surprised by the political leanings of film makers in Hollywood. While they do tend to be socially liberal, many of them are wealthy and tend to think like conservatives or libertarians when it comes to finances. That's part of the reason that people like Reagan and Schwarzenegger got elected as governors of the state despite being Republicans.

Comment: Also in MitHC the resitence is not limited to this area, it's more that the area is not "owned" by a Government and operates as a no-man's-land, where many opperatives for governments and various non-government and resistence groups may essemble. But in season 1 there was 2 Nazi agents (Joe Blake, The Origami Man) and a Nazi-hired Bounty Hunter with Julianna and the "Pacific Coast" resistence. And then at the end of the first season the Kempeitia order's trade minister to begin looking at TNZ for Uranium to mine!

Answer (score 2):

The Rocky Mountains are some of the hardest terrain to navigate in the United States. If someone was trying to lose themselves, that would be the place to do it.

In addition, with hunting/gathering there is plenty of food for a small group, that would not require the land of traditional farming. For this specific national park there are 350+ estimated mountain sheep, 500+ deer, 300+ elk, and 11 types of fish. This is in 415 square miles.
https://www.nps.gov/romo/learn/management/statistics.htm